# Netbeans - configuration for virtual host

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 8.0. I had to setup virtual host on my Apache to get

```
http://mysite.dev/index.php
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/mysite/frontend/web/index.php
```

I was trying to setup Run Configuration in Netbeans (for xdebug purpose) and it seems to be impossible. When I set `Project URL` to:

```
http://mysite.dev
```

and `Index File` simply to `index.php` there is a warning

```
Index File must be a valid relative URL
```

The warnings prevent debugging. I have no idea how to solve it.

EDIT (for @akshayb):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\mysite\frontend\web"
ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't think that matters. Netbeans doesn't even start the debug session. It just opens the `Run Configuration` window suggesting I should change `Index File` field according to the warning.

Comment: can you paste what you put in virtual host ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your project > Properties > Sources > Web Root > click Browse... and pick your root - in your case it would be "web"